# Automatically convert to upper-case

Tags: c, character

I'm a newbie to C programming and I have a problem. Here is my problem: I want to use the function '**toupper**' so that when we type a letter it automatically becomes upper-case. I want to make the letter upper-case when we type it, not when it shows in the output.

So that it just looks like this when we run the program:

Choose a letter `(A/B/C) : a`
(when we type `a` it automatically becomes A. Example under this comment.)

Choose a letter `(A/B/C) : A` (Upper-cased automatically)

This is `A`
(output)

Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a;

    printf("(A/B/C): ");
    scanf("%c", &a);

    printf("%c", a);

}
```

Thanks in advance `:D`...
 I really need your help

Comment: 7 questions and 0 accepted answers. Please go back and mark solutions to your questions that have been answered.

Comment: You can't do it with the normal standard I/O functions, you have to use something like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: `printf("hit caps lock\n");`... or more to the point, why? Since you can convert 'a' to 'A' easily... why does it matter how the user inputs the a,b,c?

Comment: You are programming in C.  Perhaps you are using a C++ compiler to compile C (it will because it is backwards compatible), but really you should remove the C++ tag unless you use some C++ code in your program.

Comment: For someone who "really needs your help", you're certainly very unconcerned about interacting with people who respond, let alone upvote or accept them.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry for not interacting.. I'm really sorry..

Comment: What Mike said ... this is something that you *shouldn't* want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using conio.h, there is a way using the getch() function. But please **note** that conio.h is non-standard C and also quite old and obsolete.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;

    printf("(A/B/C): ");
    do
    {
      ch = getch();
      ch = toupper(ch);
      printf("%c", ch);
    } while(ch != '\n');

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: ooooowwwww it's workssss :DD... THank you Lundin.. Thank you very much for your help :)... i want to ask you... i dont get it in this script ch = getch() <- can you explain it?

Comment: @messerchainey getch() is a non-standard function found in conio.h that works just like standard getchar(), with the difference that getch() returns the last character typed by the user _without echoing the character to the output and without waiting for the user to press enter_. If you want to make something more meaningful out of the code, you will need to use a string (array of characters) instead.

Comment: But as I said, please note that conio.h/getch are pretty old and not supported by many compilers. It might be a better idea to use pure platform-dependent API calls instead, such as ncurses for Linux/Posix or the console API functions in Windows.

Comment: Hello @Lundin I want to get the input from 'ch' so I can show the output with printf.. I've already try but the output didnt want to show up.

Comment: @messerchainey Post it as a separate question and include the code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Im sorry for the late reply @Lundin.. Ok I will post the question and the code later... I still have a lecturing :) Thanks for your reply

Comment: Oh it works... I just add break function in the do while script :D

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("%c", islower(a) ? toupper(a) : a );
```

Extra: `stty olcuc` works on unix.

Comment: I just want to make in console output when I type a it shows A

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread. There are only three ways: 1) (on unix) using stty to inform your terminal driver [works for lowercase -> upper case but not the other way around] 2) using curses or other terminal libraries. 3) replacing lowercase input by {destructive backspace + toupper(original input)} Extra: `stty olcuc` works on unix.

Comment: I'm sorry @wildplasser for not interacting with you just now... Thanks for your help :)